# Symfony2 Listeners and Sessions

Tags: session, symfony, listener, session-variables

I'm trying to set data of a session in a Symfony2 Listener (Symfony v. 2.0.16) but somehow the listener won't register the session variables.

I have the following:

My services.yml entry:

```
kernel.listener.domain_listener:
 class: Etiam\ClubWebBundle\Listener\SubdomainListener
 arguments: [@service_container]    
 tags:
  - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onDomainParse }
```

And here's my listener:

```
namespace Etiam\ClubWebBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

class SubdomainListener {

 private $container;

 public function __construct($container)
 {
     $this->container = $container;
 }


 public function onDomainParse(Event $event) {
  $session = $this->container->get('session');
  $session->set('siteData', '123');
  $session->save();
 }

}
```

Can anyone tell me why my session data isn't being saved when the listener is being accessed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

If anyone ever comes across something similar with Listeners that you're changing things and nothing happens:

If you have multiple bundles you've maybe got 2 identical listeners and you're editing the wrong one. Listeners are apparently global, and you need only one to be valid across multiple bundles.

You can see your loaded listeners in the profiler under events.